# AWS VPC connect to more than one Virtual Private Gateways

Tags: amazon-vpc, vpc, aws-vpc

I am trying to create VPN tunnel from VPC to office location. I have created Virtual Private Gateways and when i try to attached to VPC it says

```
Error
VPC vpc-xxxxxxxx is currently attached to the Virtual Private Gateway
```

VPC can only be attached to one Virtual Private Gateways ?

If I have to create multiple VPN tunnel to multiple office location then I have to reuse the already attached Virtual Private Gateways to VPC for VPN ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

that's correct. you will have to use the same VPG for the other VPN connections.

Answer (score 4):

> You can attach only one virtual private gateway to a VPC at a time.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/vpn-limits.html